# Reading JSON arrays from R

Tags: json, r

Then I read [JSON](http://www.json.org/) files from R using [rjson](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) it seems that JSON arrays (enclosed with `[]`) are converted to (unnamed) R lists, not vectors.

Therefore I have to first `unlist(recuresice=F)` each of those lists before I can work with them.

1. Is there any logic behind this
   conversion I am missing? I mean, why
   use a list (and not a vector) to
   store an array?
2. Is there any way to
   control this behavior of rjson (or
   perhaps another recommended JSON
   parser for R)?

Comment: The only other one I know of is here (with a brief discussion of the difference between RJSONIO and rjson):   http://www.omegahat.org/RJSONIO/

Comment: Today, I met the same situation and I also used the unlist(recursive=F) as you did. It looks a natural way to use RJSON data. However, we truly need a elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON arrays can store values of different types, so they are equivalent to R unnamed lists.

Comment: Good point; that unfortunately leaves unnamed lists partially unsupported:> toJSON(list(1,2))
[1] "[1,2]"
> toJSON(c(1,2))
[1] "[1,2]"

Comment: @piccolbo Well, it is just that the R's object model is not compatible with JavaScript's one; single-element vectors are the other example.